# Possible to drop down option list with key push - in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, html, list, input

I'm making a large input form were some of the inputs have option lists:

```
<inp class="a"> Anlegg: <input id="inpId" list="inpList"/> </inp> <br>
<inpList id="anlegg_names">
    <!-- A bunch of options <option value="Avs">  -->
</inpList>
```

And to save time when filling this form, I wonder if it is possible to assign a key make the option list drop down when focus is on the input element? Similar as when you use the mouse to click the black arrow at right of the input field, but you don't have to use the mouse.

Comment: There's no inp and inpList element in html. What framework are you using?

Comment: Sorry, those are just custom. Im using a simple <input> with a option list attached to it. Just like this:http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_list.asp

Comment: I see that arrows key (up and down) does what i want. But i have disable their default behavior (preventDefault()). So is it an easy way to toggle on and off the default behavior? Like if CTRL + Left.key makes Left.Key behave like default?